# Timing loop to simulate a process flow in Excel?

Tags: loops, simulation, timing, heartbeat

How can I implement a timing loop or a "heartbeat" to interrupt processing in Excel or in an Excel macro?

Context that will probably be asked for, such as "What are you trying to accomplish?", or "Why do you want to do that?") is provided below.

I want to use a timing loop to simulate a process flow in Excel.  The context is to simulate a process by "firing" the process steps as their required input become available from previous steps, and to randomize which steps fire to give a rough approximation of parallelism.

Comment: This is not a question, it's a statement of your opinion about how you might simulate something.  Please read the [help pages on how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: I disagree. I made it clear I had a preconception but sought other opinions and how to implement my idea or any others. I think your reaction is uncharitable - I clearly understand the rules.

Comment: If you clearly understand the rules, then you know that seeking opinion-based responses is expressly off-topic here.  It's not an issue of charitableness, it's about abiding by the charter of the site.  I also stand by my statement that you haven't actually asked a question.  There's nary a question mark to be found.